# How to access connect-mongodb-session collection

Tags: node.js, express-session

Hello I am fairly new to **connect-mongodb-session library** so I would love to know how I can access the collection of user sessions so that I can have a code logic to check if user session has expired so that I can remove it from collection.

**I know with connect-mongo:**

I can set it up like this below to check each hour for expired sessions and it automatically  removes the expired sessions

```
const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
     db: 'myappsession',
     clear_interval: 3600
});
```

**But now with connect-mongodb-session there's no prop 'clear_interval'**

**This is how my connect-mongodb-session store is made:**

```
const mongoStore = MongoStore(expressSession);

const store = new mongoStore({
  collection: "userSessions",
  uri: process.env.mongoURI,
  expires: 10 * 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60,
});
```

- So when things are like this how can I go about this

Answer (score 0):

```
var store=mongoDbStore({
    uri:connectionString,
    collection:"mySessions"
})
app.use(
session({
 secret:key,
 resave: true,
 saveUninitialized:false,
 cookie:{        
  maxAge:3600000
 },
 store:store
})
)
```

`You can give a maxAge like above. This session will be terminated.`

Comment: Your answer could be improved. Future readers will be grateful to see explained why it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.